# Python/Pandas - create row value if another row value < the column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which can be created with this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create df
data={'id':['a','b','c','d'],
      'cd':[0,4,1,3],
      'ddf':[2,5,2,5],
      0:np.nan,
      1:np.nan,
      2:np.nan,
      3:np.nan,
      4:np.nan,
      5:np.nan,
      6:np.nan
      }
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)[['id','cd','ddf',0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

and looks like this:

```
df
Out[35]: 
  id  cd  ddf   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0  a   0    2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  b   4    5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  c   1    2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3  d   3    5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

What I want to do is calculate the difference between the column name for columns 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and df['cd'] -->IF the column name is >= to `df['cd']` AND the column name is <= to `df['ddf']`.  The resulting `df` should look like:

```
df
Out[45]: 
  id  cd  ddf    0    1    2    3    4    5   6
0  a   0    2  0.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
1  b   4    5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0 NaN
2  c   1    2  NaN  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
3  d   3    5  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0 NaN
```

I have successfully filled the first part of the IF clause using:

```
df.loc[:,j]=(j-i[:,None])
```

where:

```
i=df.cd.values
j=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But having a problem doing the "`column name is <= to df['ddf']`" part.  Ideally we can do both together.  Speed will be very important as the full dataframe is very large at >100m rows and `j` having a length of roughly 4,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `numpy` broadcast

```
s1=df.cd.values
s2=df.ddf.values
s=df.columns[3:].values
t=(s1[:,None]-s<=0)&(s2[:,None]-s>=0)
updf=pd.DataFrame(t.cumsum(axis=1),columns=s,index=df.index)
df.update((updf-1).where(t))
df
Out[590]: 
  id  cd  ddf    0    1    2    3    4    5   6
0  a   0    2  0.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
1  b   4    5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0 NaN
2  c   1    2  NaN  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN
3  d   3    5  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a way

```
i=df.cd.values
j=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
df.loc[:,j]=(j-i[:,None])
print(df)


for c in j : 
  for l in  range(df.shape[0]) :
    if c < df.cd[l] or c > df.ddf[l] : 
      df[c][l] = np.nan 

df
```

output :

```
    id  cd  ddf 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   a   0   2   0.0 1.0 2.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   b   4   5   NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 1.0 NaN
2   c   1   2   NaN 0.0 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   d   3   5   NaN NaN NaN 0.0 1.0 2.0 NaN
```

Comment: does work but longer than the selected solution probably due to the loops...thx.